# AngularJS call another directives function

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive on a page that applies colours to it's elements.
It might look like this:

```
.directive('colours', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            colours: '='
        },
        template: '<div class="col-md-4" id="panel-1"><p>This is panel 1</p></div><div class="col-md-4" id="panel-2"><p>This is panel 2</p></div><div class="col-md-4" id="panel-3"><p>This is panel 3</p></div>',
        link: function (scope, element) {

            // Get our panel children
            var children = element.children();

            // This is just an example, so excuse the code
            for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                var child = angular.element(children[i]);

                child.css('background-color', scope.colours[i]);
            }
        }
    };
})
```

It is just an example, but the real directive has database colours, svgs, etc, so I could not replicate it in codepen.
What I want to do is create a new directive on the same view (but not a child of the **colours** directive). It might look like this:

```
.directive('colourSwapper', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            colours: '=colourSwapper'
        },
        template: '<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="swap(true)"><span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span></button> Swap colours <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="swap()">    <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></button>',
        link: function (scope, element) {

            // Get our colours
            var colours = scope.colours;

            // Create our function
            scope.swap = function (opposite) {

                // If we want to go in the opposite direction
                if (opposite) {

                    // Shift the array in reverse
                    colours.unshift(colours.pop());

                // Else
                } else {

                    // Shift the array
                    colours.push(colours.shift());
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

I have passed the same array of colours to this directive. What I want to do now, is change the order of the colours and then reapply them to the element.
I would like to be able to call a function rather than adding a watch (The reason for that is my colours directive is a child of a parent which requires a few directives and I don't want to have too many watches in them. I am assuming that too many watches is a bad thing).

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ng-style to bind the colors in scope variable. Then changing the scope variable will update the color. Also it is important to compile after adding the ng-style attribute.

http://plnkr.co/edit/MmcnkWLhaVKZmLonhzlx?p=preview

```
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      var child = angular.element(children[i]);

      child.attr('ng-style', '{\'background-color\': colours[' + i + ']}');
      $compile(child)(scope);
    }
```